# Filter with array key in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, filter, nosql, key, couchdb

I want to filter documents by a value that contains the array in the key field that returns the design view that I make.

```
// _design/products/_view/all
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type && doc.type == 'producto'){
        emit([doc.created, doc.user], doc);
    }
}
```

The result:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"64243f77b5135758d1f0d55c250001f5","key":[1364931254000,"samuelb1311"],"value":{"_id":"64243f77b5135758d1f0d55c250001f5","_rev":"3-50f67780d6388f3aad469dbdd1081b9e","nombre":"limon","precio":250,"user":"samuelb1311","created":1364931254000,"type":"producto"}},
{"id":"64243f77b5135758d1f0d55c2500058e","key":[1364931381000,"samuel123"],"value":{"_id":"64243f77b5135758d1f0d55c2500058e","_rev":"3-c1f893af011ee5a3687b0a9eeedc3467","nombre":"lima","precio":360,"user":"samuel123","created":1364931381000,"type":"producto"}},
{"id":"64243f77b5135758d1f0d55c25000e7a","key":[1364931447000,"samuelb1311"],"value":{"_id":"64243f77b5135758d1f0d55c25000e7a","_rev":"3-2b05730dfcf3407b7335ec029e5cfdc5","nombre":"naranja","precio":25,"user":"samuelb1311","created":1364931447000,"type":"producto"}}
]}
```

I need the date in the key for sorting the info in order ascending and descending from the first inserted to the last inserted and vice versa.
So, how can I filter the info by an user, for example by the user "samuelb1311" or the user "samuel123" ? 
I try things like startkey and endkey, but this not working for me, thats returning empty response. 
Thanks for some info you can bring me!

Answer (score 3):

You need to reverse the order or the timestamp and the user in order to be able to get only entries for a certain user. That's because when you want to use startkey/endkey, you can only get a continuous range from the entries sorted by key. Then use startkey and endkey like this:

```
startkey=["foo"]&endkey=["foo","a"]
```

Have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation?action=show&redirect=ViewCollation.

Comment: I try things like this:
localhost:5984/crud/_design/productos/_view/all?descending=true&startkey=[{}]&endkey=[0,"samuelb1311"]

But this return all the data for all the users, so, don't work.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what @thejh has said. You need to change your emit to emit([doc.user, doc.created], ...), your start key would be ["samuelb1311"], your end key ["samuelb1311", {}]

Comment: but if I do this, the order of the products would be in alphabetic order from the username

Comment: @SamuelBR: I thought you only wanted to select ONE user?

Comment: @thejh no hehe, your answer clarify me, now I have two views in my Database and all is working perfectly.
One view return by key the date for ordering and the Second view return me an array key of user and date for ordering and filter as you can say.
Thank you very much!